# How to write company name

Tags: proper-nouns

This is the name of a company:

> Taobao Network Co., Ltd.

Is it correct that every first letter is capitalised? Also, why is there a comma?

Comment: The correct way to write a company name is to write it as the company registered its own name. There aren't English rules about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a company is a proper noun--like a person's name, or a country. This [GrammarGirl tutorial](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/Capitalizing-Proper-Nouns.aspx) explains that you need to capitalize proper nouns.

The comma is necessary, because "Taobao Network Co., Ltd." is how the company registered their name. However, you will find that most company titles are of the form "Company Name, Type of Company". An ["LTD"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTD)  is:

> a business incorporated under the laws of England, Wales, Scotland, Canada, other Commonwealth countries, the Republic of Ireland, Cyprus, Israel and some Anglophone countries in Africa, like Ghana or Nigeria.

So the comma separates the part of the full title. Not every company has an abbreviation like "Ltd" or "LLC", so you won't always see one.

Comment: Actually, if it doesn't have 'Ltd' (for limited company) 'LLC' (for Limited Liability Company) or some equivalent, it's not a company but a firm.  The difference probably only matters to lawyers.

Comment: The comma is only *required* because Taobao registered the name in that form.  "Marks and Spencer, plc" would be as wrong as "Taobao Network Co Ltd" (i.e. technically a mistake, but not one to worry about).

Comment: @TimL: I edited my answer to include your point about registering names in that form.